# SSIS capturing 6 row count variables (added, deleted, updated, etc.) to add a row to a "stats" table

Tags: ssis

We are processing rows of data from a REST API which is working well. We put that data into a SQL Server db, also working well.

We would like statistics about the process, like how many records did we process, add, delete, update, etc. I have added 6 Row Count components to get the desired counts. It appears they are getting the number as it appears along with the green dot with the white check mark.

**Note:** *I am testing in Visual Studio.*

I have added to the Control Flow an Execute SQL Task which I set up to write 1 row to the stats table. If I run the INSERT INTO  in SSMS it works fine. If I  and run just that task it inserts a row with 0 for each numeric field (that is expected). However, the task either doesn't get triggered or it is erring (only indication that this might be the issue is this message in Visual Studio: Information: 0x4004300B at ServiceNow Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: **"Insert if not found" wrote 0 rows.**).

Here is the SQL Query that should execute:

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[SSISAgentJobStatistics] 
([SSISPackage],
[JobName],
[AddedRecords],
[UpdatedRecords],
[DeletedRecords],
[IgnoredRecords],
[InactiveRecords],
[TotalRecordsFromAPI])
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**Here is the contents of the Output window:**
SSIS package "c:\CHWSource\Custom\Intranet2015\Directory2023
SSIS\Directory2023 SSIS\ServiceNowImport.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at ServiceNow Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline:
Validation phase is beginning.

Warning: 0x80047076 at ServiceNow Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column "matchDeviceID" (160) on output "Lookup Match Output" (159) and component "Reference Target Table - Lookup" (141) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.

Information: 0x40043006 at ServiceNow Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at ServiceNow Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.

Information: 0x400490F4 at ServiceNow Data Flow Task, Lookup [116]: Lookup has cached 15 rows.
Information: 0x400490F5 at ServiceNow Data Flow Task, Lookup [116]: Lookup has cached a total of 15 rows.

Information: 0x40209340 at ServiceNow Data Flow Task, Lookup [116]: The number of unique rows added to the cache is 15.

Information: 0x402090E2 at ServiceNow Data Flow Task, Lookup [116]: The Lookup processed 15 rows in the cache. The processing time was 0.001 seconds. The cache used 1350 bytes of memory.

Information: 0x4004300C at ServiceNow Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.

Information: 0x40043008 at ServiceNow Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.

**Information: 0x4004300B at ServiceNow Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "Insert if not found" wrote 0 rows.**

Information: 0x40043009 at ServiceNow Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.

SSIS package "c:\CHWSource\Custom\Intranet2015\Directory2023
SSIS\Directory2023 SSIS\ServiceNowImport.dtsx" finished: Success.

---

### **QUESTION:** Any thoughts on why that task is not executing or failing?

---

[image: Variables list]

[image: Data Flow Task]

[image: Execute SQL Task]

[image: After completion I see this in the Control Flow]